# Armijo criterion example

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $d_{k}$ be a descent direction for the function $f$ in $x_{k}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
Armijo criterion is 
$$
f(x_{k}+td_{k})\leq f(x_{k})+\alpha t\nabla f(x_{k})^{T}d_{k}
$$

I have to find a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for
which every  $t>0$ does not satisfy Armijo criterion when $\alpha=1$.
Can anyone help me with an example of function please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any [strongly convex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Strongly_convex_functions) satisfies, in particular, 
$$
f(x+td)>f(x)+t\nabla f(x)^Td, \quad t\ne 0,\ d\ne 0.
$$
Hence, it cannot get $\le$ at the same time.

For example, $f(x)=\|x-a\|^2$, $x_k=0$, $d_k=a$, for any nonzero vector $a\in\Bbb{R}^n$ .